# Is it not possible to add a property to a PsCustomObject with 'psobject.Properties.Add()'?

Tags: powershell

Reading Kevin Marquette's excellent article again, [Powershell: Everything you wanted to know about PSCustomObject](https://powershellexplained.com/2016-10-28-powershell-everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-pscustomobject/), he shows that its possible to remove a property from a `[PsCustomObject]` with the following:

```
$SomeObject.psobject.properties.remove('SomeProperty')
```

I really like this as it is consistent with working with hashtables (`$hash.remove()`) and means I can avoid piping things to `Select-Object` or `Where-Object`.

Now I just need a `add()` method, looking around I discovered that there is a `add()` method in `$SomeObject.psobject.properties`:

```
void Add(System.Management.Automation.PSPropertyInfo member)
void Add(System.Management.Automation.PSPropertyInfo member, bool preValidated)
```

But trying to use it gives me an error:

```
$o.psobject.Properties.Add("bar", "bar")

#MethodException: Cannot find an overload for "Add" and the argument count: "2".
```

Am I doing this the wrong way??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're going the right path but as you can see in the method's overloads, both take a [`PSPropertyInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.pspropertyinfo?view=powershellsdk-7.4.0) as their first argument, and this type is an [`abstract` type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/abstract) so you would need to use any type inheriting this base class instead, if you want to add a new property to your object for example, you would be using [`PSNoteProperty`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.psnoteproperty?view=powershellsdk-7.4.0):

```bash
$someobject = [psobject]::new()
$someobject.PSObject.Properties.Add([psnoteproperty]::new('foo', 'bar'))
$someobject

# foo
# ---
# bar
```

This is essentially how [`Add-Member`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-member?view=powershell-7.4) works behind the scenes when you're looking to add a new property to the `psobject` wrapper.

If you want to find out all types that could be inheriting `PSPropertyInfo` you can use the [ClassExplorer Module](https://github.com/SeeminglyScience/ClassExplorer):

```bash
Find-Type -InheritsType System.Management.Automation.PSPropertyInfo

#    Namespace: System.Management.Automation
# 
# Access        Modifiers           Name
# ------        ---------           ----
# public        class               PSAliasProperty : PSPropertyInfo
# public        class               PSCodeProperty : PSPropertyInfo
# public        class               PSProperty : PSPropertyInfo
# public        class               PSAdaptedProperty : PSProperty
# public        class               PSNoteProperty : PSPropertyInfo
# public        class               PSVariableProperty : PSNoteProperty
# public        class               PSScriptProperty : PSPropertyInfo
```

Or you can filter those types in your [AppDomain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain?view=net-8.0) where their `.BaseType` contains `PSPropertyInfo`, do note this query would return less results because it only filters 1 level up in the base type hierarchy:

```bash
[System.AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().GetTypes() |
    Where-Object BaseType -EQ ([System.Management.Automation.PSPropertyInfo]) |
    Where-Object IsPublic

#    Namespace: System.Management.Automation
# 
# Access        Modifiers           Name
# ------        ---------           ----
# public        class               PSAliasProperty : PSPropertyInfo
# public        class               PSCodeProperty : PSPropertyInfo
# public        class               PSProperty : PSPropertyInfo
# public        class               PSNoteProperty : PSPropertyInfo
# public        class               PSScriptProperty : PSPropertyInfo
```